# Does the data of Galois group, ramified places, and inertia groups, determine a Galois number field?

Tags: reference-request, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

Suppose I tell you that $K/\mathbb{Q}$ is a finite Galois extension, and I specify the Galois group $G$, and suppose further that I give you a finite list $S$ of places of $\mathbb{Q}$ and for each place $p$ a conjugacy class $C_p$ of subgroups of $G$, and I tell you that $K/\mathbb{Q}$ is ramified precisely at the places $p$ of $S$, with inertia groups $C_p$.

Is this enough information to recover $K$?

If not, can you provide a counterexample? If so, can you refer me to some sources (or, if the proof is not too hard, can you indicate lines of proof)?

ADDENDUM August 8: To clarify a point. The list $S$ is allowed to include the infinite place. If the infinite place is ramified, i.e. if $K$ is not a real field, then, fixing some embedding of $K$ in $\mathbb{C}$, $G$ contains complex conjugation and the relevant conjugacy class $C_\infty$ is that of the subgroup generated by complex conjugation. So, the data $S,\{C_p\}$ that we start with includes whether the infinite place is ramified.

Comment: This seems unlikely; it's just not a whole lot of information. I would look for counterexamples among number fields with the same Dedekind zeta function (see for example http://mathoverflow.net/questions/23571/number-fields-with-same-discriminant-and-regulator for some references).

Comment: Something along these lines which is true is that a number field (I'm not sure if it has to be Galois or not) is determined by which primes split completely in it, although I don't know a reference for this.

Comment: We can probably use already-available global class field theory to answer this for abelian groups.

Comment: Aren't the completely split primes exactly those with trivial inertia groups (outside of $S$?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen - no, the inertia group is trivial iff there is no ramification, but there can be some inertia.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen - the "inertia group" and "decomposition group" are so named because of their fixed fields.  In the decomposition field, a prime of the base field does all the splitting it will do, and the primes above it in the decomposition field then stay inert in the inertia field, whereupon, passing to the top field, they ramify. This is why trivial inertia group $\Leftrightarrow$ inertia field is the top field $\Leftrightarrow$ no ramification.

Comment: Oops. You're right. I had the wrong recollection that inertia group has order $f$, but it is of index $f$ in the decomposition group. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ferra's $K$ and $L$ are distinguished by the infinite place, but they inspired me to look for simple quadratic counterexamples:

Take $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$ and $L=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{6})$. These are both ramified at 2 and 3 and because the Galois group of both is $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, whose only nontrivial subgroup is the whole group, the inertia groups at both 2 and 3 must be the whole group.  Then $K$ and $L$ cannot be distinguished by the information specified in the question.

Actually, for any squarefree $m$ that is $>0$ and $3$ mod $4$, $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{m})$ and $L=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2m})$ would also always provide a counterexample, because the discriminants are $4m$ and $8m$ and these are divisible by the same primes, so they are ramified at the same places.

Answer (score 2):

I would say no. For example, take $K=\mathbb Q(i)$ and $L=\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2})$, which are non-isomorphic number field. Both are ramified precisely at $2$, and the inertia subgroup at $2$ is the whole Galois group. So if I tell you $G=C_2$, $S=\{2\}$ and $C_2=G$, you are not able to recover exactly one between $K$ and $L$.

Comment: I was satisfied when I read this, but actually it's occurring to me now that if we admit the infinite place (which I absolutely want to do), then $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ is ramified at the infinite place but $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ isn't.